# Baysian multivariate linear regression using bas.lm() in r

Tags: r, bayesian

```
spr_bas <- bas.lm(spr ~ .,
                     data = sp500,
                     method = "MCMC",
                     prior = "ZS-null",
                     modelprior = uniform())
```

I want to use bas.lm() to run a bayesian linear regression with informative prior (N(0,10),gamma(5,5)). But I look for the method bas.lm(), I do not know where I can put my informative prior since in the arguments of bas.lm(...), there are no option for normal or gamma in prior or modelprior options

Comment: I haven't used this package, but the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BAS/vignettes/BAS-vignette.html) lists the types of priors that are available.

Comment: I did check the vignette, but still do not know where I can set the value with informative prior((N(0,10), Gamma(10/2,1*10/2)). Maybe prior="g-prior", but again, I do not know where I can input the value N(0,10), Gamma(10/2,1*10/2)